# android: 1M records to lookup in database

Tags: android, database, performance, sqlite

I'm going to develop a phonebook-like application which is going to lookup among one million records for specified name. One of my main concerns is performance of lookups.
So my questions are:

1- Is it feasible to have a SQLite database in android with 1M records?

2- Are there any know solutions to speed up database queries?

About 2nd question it comes to my mind to use Indexing and also breaking up database to several smaller databases.
In case it is not feasible are there any know methods to handle this?

Comment: Could you please describe the math you used to get to one million for a specified name?

Comment: "Is it feasible to have a SQLite database in android with 1M records?" -- that cannot be answered the abstract. It depends a lot on the database structure and the nature of your queries. Lots of joins, for example, will be a problem. "Are there any know solutions to speed up database queries?" -- indexes. Also, depending upon how you were planning on doing your name lookups, use FTS3/FTS4 instead of `LIKE`. "also breaking up database to several smaller databases" -- that would seem to make matters worse.

Comment: there is no smart phone can take one million record database, try to use an external database.

Comment: I've only read a little bit about it, but it seems like database size is a bigger issue than number of rows.  How big would your database be?  From what I saw less than 1 GB should be OK.  And indexing will generally be a good way to improve query performance.  As for using multiple databases, I read that one database per table is no longer needed with recent versions of sqlite.

Comment: @OussemaAroua what do you mean by external databases? You mean database is going to be located out of phone?

Comment: @OussemaAroua Why do you say that?  Do you have experience with failures on databases over a million rows, or references that indicate it's not feasible?  If each row is small, a million of them wouldn't necessarily be all that much data.

Comment: it's about what you will store, but 1 million record to select from and search still a big number

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have a database with 1M records. If the database is not pre-populated then you can proceed the normal way however if you want to use a pre-populated database, you can't rely on assets raw folder because the size limit is 10mb but you can use the following library, which copies the database from assets folder when your app is first launched. 
https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

The other solution is to put your data on a server maybe amazon AWS for fast data processing and call the server from your app (GET request).

You can test everything pretty easily. Get a sample SQL database which contains 4M rows from here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/employees-introduction.html. Convert the data to sqlite and use the android-sqlite-asset-helper to use it in your app.